# How do I use truth tables to prove Entailment?

Tags: logic

For example, consider an agent concerned with predicting the weather, with variable R indicating whether or not it is likely to rain, variable C indicating whether or not it is cloudy, and variable L indicating low pressure. Given knowledge base K:

L (Pressure is low)

C (It is cloudy)

C ∧ L ⇒ R, (Clouds and low pressure imply rain)

the agent may conclude R; thus, the agent’s knowledge implies that R is true, because K |= R.

Similarly, given knowledge base L:

¬L (Pressure is high)

C (It is cloudy)

C ∧ L ⇒ R, (Clouds and low pressure imply rain)

the agent cannot conclude that R is true; L 6|= R

Deriving a truth table:

L   C   r   ((L ∧ C) → r)

F   F   F   T

F   F   T   T

F   T   F   T

F   T   T   T

T   F   F   T

T   F   T   T

T   T   F   F

T   T   T   T

but this does not make sense.

Comment: Answer to this question is explained perfectly in the following slides: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15381-s07/www/slides/022707reasoning.pdf